# Django - creating a DB scheme from model inspite of existing code

Tags: django, django-migrations

I'm using Django 1.9 and somewhere in the development process the migrations tool stopped working and was throwing strange errors, therefore I wanted to start off with a new database (MySQL). So I removed all old migrations, created a new initial one with `manage.py makemigrations`, switched to a new empty DB in the settings and wanted to run `manage.py migrate`. The problem is that some of might existing code calls to tables that are not yet present in the new DB and this actually throws an error when I execute `migrate`.

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'new_db.old_table' doesn't exist")
```

How can I circumvent this problem?

Comment: Try use `python manage migrate --fake` and then `migrate` again

Comment: So `--fake` throws exactly the same error, but I have managed the issue now with temporarily commenting the code out, though this is for sure no satisfactory solution for larger projects.

Comment: @Jano you commented depencies to `old_table` in other migration file? Maybe problem is that `old_table` have no initial migration and `manage.py migrate --fake-initial`  could help. Or maybe you just need create single `makemigration` to this table, like `manage.py makemigrations old_table` and then `migrate` it

Comment: @Baterson In fact, I removed all old migrations from the migrations folder and generate a new initial migration. The problem is SomeModel.objects.all() statement, that can't find its table in this state.